# Need to have a Role based security access to Device Editor section at Presentation page

Tags: security, role-management

I need to configure Role-based access for the `Placeholder settings` section, how to achieve this?

Any suggestion would be helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Marek, your suggestion got worked out.

- Check **DeviceEditor** control (**sitecore\shell\Applications\Layouts\DeviceEditor\DeviceEditor.xml**)
- Change **CodeBeside** to your custom class inheriting from the original Sitecore.(**Shell.Applications.Layouts.DeviceEditor.DeviceEditorForm**)
- Overwrite OnLoad method to hide **PlaceholdersTab** from the DeviceEditor.xml

Here is the custom logic to restrict the access to specific role:

```
public class DeviceEditorForm : Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Layouts.DeviceEditor.DeviceEditorForm
{
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull(e, "e");
        base.OnLoad(e);
        if (!Context.ClientPage.IsEvent && Sitecore.Context.User.IsInRole(ContentAuthor))
        {
            Placeholders.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember there is nothing like that out of the box

You would need to:

- check `DeviceEditor` control (most probably it's `sitecore\shell\Applications\Layouts\DeviceEditor\DeviceEditor.xml`)
- change `CodeBeside` to your custom class inheriting from the original `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Layouts.DeviceEditor.DeviceEditorForm`
- overwrite `OnLoad` method to hide `PlaceholdersTab` from the `DeviceEditor.xml`.

Comment: Hi @Marek , Thanks for your suggestion, I tried multiple ways to hide "PlaceholderTab" I couldn't achieved it. Could share me a code snippet to Hide the "PlaceholderTab", if you have?

Comment: I've never done that on my own. You can edit your question and add the code you tried with. Maybe someone will be able to help you